# d3.layout.histogram() returning wrong output

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using this code for a histogram layout for d3.js using the dataset. However, the starting position of the rectangles is not 0. As per the histogram layout, starting position should always be 0 but somehow I am not getting 0. Kindly help me out buy pointing if there are any errors.

Thanks.

Reference tutorial video - https://youtu.be/0CZ7-f9wXiM?list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tewjyfed/

```
create(dataset);        


function create(data) {        
    var map =  data.map(function(i) { return parseInt(i.skill) });
    var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
                        .bins(7)
                        (map);

    var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(histogram.map(function(i) { return i.length }))])
                    .range([0, height]);

    var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(map)])
                    .range([0, width]);

    var axis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xscale)
                    .orient('bottom');

    var bar = svg.selectAll('bar')
                .data(histogram)
                .enter()
                .append('g');

    bar.append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) { return  xscale(d.x)})
        .attr('y', function(d) { return height - yscale(d.y) })
        .attr('width', function(d) { return xscale(d.dx) })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return yscale(d.y)})
        .attr('fill', 'lightsteelblue')
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue');

        svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, '+height +')')                     
        .call(axis);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the range of the histogram is the min/max of the data, so it starts from 5. You can specify it explicitly though to go from 0, by calling `.histogram().range([0, d3.max(map)])`.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rm9tozcg/

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var padding = 50;
var dataset = [
{"name": "a", "skill": 60},
{"name": "b", "skill": 65},
{"name": "c", "skill": 23},
{"name": "d", "skill": 47},
{"name": "e", "skill": 38},
{"name": "f", "skill": 27},
{"name": "g", "skill": 24},
{"name": "h", "skill": 16},
{"name": "i", "skill": 36},
{"name": "j", "skill": 57},
{"name": "k", "skill": 77},
{"name": "l", "skill": 5},
{"name": "m", "skill": 46},
{"name": "n", "skill": 29},
{"name": "o", "skill": 55},
{"name": "p", "skill": 68},
{"name": "q", "skill": 40},
{"name": "r", "skill": 21},
{"name": "s", "skill": 14},
{"name": "t", "skill": 5},
{"name": "u", "skill": 63},
{"name": "v", "skill": 99},
{"name": "w", "skill": 89},
{"name": "x", "skill": 77},
{"name": "y", "skill": 12},
{"name": "z", "skill": 90}
];



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + 100)
        .attr("height", height + padding)
            .append("g")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(20,0)')

    create(dataset);        


    function create(data) {        
        var map =  data.map(function(i) { return parseInt(i.skill) });
        var maxValue = d3.max(map);

        var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
                            .range([0, maxValue])
                            .bins(7)
                            (map);

        var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(histogram.map(function(i) { return i.length }))])
                        .range([0, height]);

        var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, maxValue])
                        .range([0, width]);

        var axis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xscale)
                        .orient('bottom');

        var bar = svg.selectAll('bar')
                    .data(histogram)
                    .enter()
                    .append('g');

        bar.append('rect')
            .attr('x', function(d) { return  xscale(d.x)})
            .attr('y', function(d) { return height - yscale(d.y) })
            .attr('width', function(d) { return xscale(d.dx) })
            .attr('height', function(d) { return yscale(d.y)})
            .attr('fill', 'lightsteelblue')
            .attr('stroke', 'steelblue');

            svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, '+height +')')                     
            .call(axis);

}
```